# Django's prefetch_related and select_related on more complex relationships in Admin

Tags: django

I have a somewhat complex relationship between multiple models. A simplified example:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField([...])
    [...]

    def __ str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class Region(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    name = models.CharField([...])
    [...]

    def __ str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class CityManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().select_related('region', 'region__country')

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField([...])
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region)

    objects = CityManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.region.country} - {self.region} - {self.name}'
```

Hence when I want to display some kind of list of `cities` (e.g. list all cities in Germany), I have to use `select_related` to be even remotely efficient otherwise I query for `Country` each time the `__str__` is called. This is not the problem.

The problem is that when I have unrelated group of models and I want to FK to `City`, such as:

```
class Tour(models.Model):
    [...]

class TourItem(models.Model):
    tour = models.ForeignKey(Tour)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    [...]
```

`Tour` would represent a planned tour for some music band; and `TourItem` would be a specific tour in a given city. I have a simple admin interface for this, so that `TourItem` is an inline field for the `Tour` (ie. so multiple tour items can be edited/added simultaneously). The problem is that now there are multiple queries firing for same `Country` when looking up the `City` FK and I'm not sure how to solve it. I tried what follows, but it did not work as expected:

```
class TourManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().prefetch_related('touritem_set__city', 'touritem_set__city__region', 'touritem_set__city__region__country')
```

And neither did this work:

```
class TourItemManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().select_related('city', 'city__region', 'city__region__country')
```

How can I adjust the managers/models so that when I load Tour's admin there will not be additional queries fired for `Country`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ModelAdmin [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related) to select related tables

> `list_select_related = ('author', 'category')`

If that is not fully helpful and you still want to do override try with following in your custom Manager

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
   return super(TourItemManager,self).queryset(request).select_related('city', 'city__region', 'city__region__country')
```

Comment: @phoenix please be careful regarding text additions :)

Comment: From what I can tell of the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47534722/revisions), I only changed the link. The other typo was there before I edited, right?

Comment: Yes sorry my bad